# Select parents that have no children in a self-join relationship

Tags: sql, ms-access, self-join

I have a simple table of category names that relates to itself with a category_parent = id. I need to select records that have no children.

From other answers I have cobbled together this statement:

```
SELECT cat.category_name AS 'Child Name', cat.id AS 'Child ID',
cat.category_parent AS 'Childs Parent', cat_par.category_name AS 'Parent Name', 
cat_par.id AS 'Parent ID'
FROM category AS cat
LEFT JOIN category AS cat_par ON cat.category_parent = cat_par.id
WHERE cat_par.id IS NULL;
```

This will successfully select records that have no PARENT. I tried changing the last clause to `WHERE cat.category_parent IS NULL` but that yielded an empty yet.

I have also tried this statement based on another answer:

```
SELECT cat.category_name AS 'Child Name', cat.id AS 'Child ID', 
cat.category_parent AS 'Childs Parent' cat_par.category_name AS 'Parent Name', 
cat_par.id AS 'Parent ID'
FROM category AS cat
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM category AS cat_par WHERE cat.category_parent = cat_par.id);
```

Which returns the error `No value given for one or more required parameters.`

Comment: what's the reason why you'rechangin the where in `cat.category_parent IS NULL` wherein the first query is already working?

Comment: The first query worked to find parents with no children, but not children with no parents. I thought changing that last WHERE would do it.

Comment: do you need only the id and category_name of records with no children, or do you also need their parent name?

Comment: Thanks everyone for their answers. All the answers supplied did work, although most of them took 100+ seconds to execute on this Access file. The chosen answer took less than 1 second. Finding the name of the parent was optional and a mistake on my part in the original question. If I required that then Tobsey's answer would have been chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the id and the category name of records with no children this also works:

```
SELECT
  category.id,
  category.category_name
FROM
  category LEFT JOIN category AS category_1
    ON category.id = category_1.category_parent
WHERE
  category_1.category_parent IS NULL
```

and i think this query looks nice. But if you also need the parent's name, you can use this:

```
SELECT
  category.id,
  category.category_name,
  category_1.category_name
FROM
  (category LEFT JOIN category AS category_2
    ON category.id = category_2.category_parent)
  LEFT JOIN category AS category_1
    ON category.category_parent = category_1.ID
WHERE
  category_2.category_parent Is Null;
```

and yes, it gets a little more complicated: it's just a nice sql exercise but i would prefer to use the Exists version instead.

Comment: Thanks. Your top query most closely matched the one I was trying to write, and it also executed the fastest of the other answers I tried running.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select p.id, p.category_name
From category As p
Where Not Exists (
  Select 'x' 
  From Category c 
  Where c.category_parent = p.id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand the relation enough. How about this?

```
SELECT cat.*
FROM category cat
WHERE cat.id not in (
   SELECT distinct category_parent FROM category
);
```

Comment: It looks like my setup (it is unfortunately an .mdb Access file) has troubles with lines like "SELECT distinct category_parent FROM category". This is the second time I've tried to run a query with a similar statement and both times it has frozen and had a process needing to be killed

Comment: This did end up working when I let it run. It took about 400 seconds. Thanks and sorry for the omission.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the second query is that you are trying to include `cat_par.category_name` in your results set, even though it's not in your `FROM` clause. You cannot return a column from the tables in your EXISTS subquery.

YOu want the following:

```
SELECT 
    cat.category_name AS 'Child Name', 
    cat.id AS 'Child ID', 
    cat.category_parent AS 'Childs Parent',
    cat_par.category_name AS 'Parent Name',
    cat_par.id AS 'Parent ID'
FROM 
    category AS cat
    LEFT JOIN category AS cat_par ON cat.category_parent = cat_par.id
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 
        NULL 
    FROM 
        category AS cat_childless 
    WHERE cat.id = cat_childless.category_parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- get parents categories without children

SELECT id, category_name
FROM category
WHERE id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT c.id
    FROM category c, category p
    WHERE c.parent_id = p.id
) 
AND id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT p.id
    FROM category c, category p
    WHERE c.parent_id = p.id
)
```

EXPLANATION: The logic here is very simple. With the query below (used inside both NOT IN) we get parent categories and its children:

```
SELECT c.id, p.id
FROM category c, category p
WHERE c.parent_id = p.id
```

As NOT IN only allows comparison with one column, we use it twice:

Once to get the inverse of the parents, another to get the inverse of the children. What's left are "parents" without children.